# Unity failed to re-package resources (using onesignal)

Tags: unity-game-engine, sdk, apk, onesignal

I updated my Onesignal Unity Apk files using the latest unitypackage available and i have not been able to compile for android since then. I've tried using different Android SDK Tools and unity versions.
I'm honestly out of ideas, any help will be appreciated. I'm using Uniwebview and Onesignal (just for the push notifications) plugins and unity 5.6.0f3 (it's not a problem to change versions if i need to).

> `C:\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\build-tools-23.0.1\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J "gen" -M "AndroidManifest.xml" -S "res" -I`
>
> "C:/Android/android-sdk\platforms\android-26\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages"C:\Users\JuanPC\Documents\tcervantes_unity\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\android.arch.lifecycle.livedata-core-1.1.0\res" -S "C:\Users\JuanPC\Documents\tcervantes_unity\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\android.arch.lifecycle.runtime-1.1.0\res" -S "C:\Users\JuanPC\Documents\tcervantes_unity\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\android.arch.lifecycle.viewmodel-1.1.0\res" -S "C:\Users\JuanPC\Documents\tcervantes_unity\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.animated-vector-drawable-28.0.0-alpha1\res" -S

I've made a pastebin with the complete error.
[Full error here](https://pastebin.com/LNZkctJV)

Comment: Have you updated your Android SDK?

Comment: Yes, i have. I even tried using older versions (since i read that the newer versions may cause this issue)

Comment: What other plugins are you using besides OneSignal?

Comment: Uniwebview, and that's it.